# Custom Taxonomy Not Showing Up on Post Page

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy

I have a custom post type with a custom taxonomy that has been working fine for years, but recently I've seen that the **custom taxonomy doesn't show up in the individual custom post type anymore**. However, it does show up in the listing and I can quick edit it just fine.

[image]

I disabled all our plugins and the same issue. Any ideas on what I'm missing?

This is the code I have to build the custom post type and taxonomy.

```
// Register Profiles
function cpt_profiles() {
    $labels = array(
        'name' => __( 'Profile', 'profile' ),
        'singular_name' => __( 'Profile', 'profile' ),
        'add_new' => __( 'Add Profile', 'profile' ),
        'all_items' => __( 'All Profiles', 'profile' ),
        'add_new_item' => __( 'Add New Profile', 'profile' ),
        'edit_item' => __( 'Edit Profile', 'profile' ),
        'new_item' => __( 'New Profile', 'profile' ),
        'view_item' => __( 'View Profile', 'profile' ),
        'search_items' => __( 'Search Profiles', 'profile' ),
        'not_found' => __( 'No Profiles found', 'profile' ),
        'not_found_in_trash' => __( 'No Profiles found in Trash', 'profile' ),
        'parent_item_colon' => __( 'Parent Profile:', 'profile' ),
        'menu_name' => __( 'Profiles', 'profile' ),
    );
    $rewrite = array(
        'slug'                  => 'profile',
        'with_front'            => false,
        'pages'                 => true,
        'feeds'                 => true,
    );
    $args = array(
        'labels' => $labels,
        'hierarchical' => false,
        'supports' => array( 'title', 'editor', 'author', 'revisions', 'thumbnail'),
        'taxonomies' => array( 'profile_category'),
        'public' => true,
        'show_ui' => true,
        'show_in_menu' => true,
        'show_in_rest' => true,
        'menu_position' => 10,
        'menu_icon' => 'dashicons-universal-access',
        'show_in_nav_menus' => false,
        'publicly_queryable' => true,
        'exclude_from_search' => false,
        'has_archive' => true,
        'query_var' => true,
        'can_export' => true,
        'rewrite' => $rewrite,
        'capability_type' => 'post'
    );

    register_post_type( 'profile', $args );
}
add_action( 'init', 'cpt_profiles' );

// Register Profile Areas
function tax_profile_topics() {

    $labels = array(
        'name'                       => _x( 'Areas', 'Taxonomy General Name', 'text_domain' ),
        'singular_name'              => _x( 'Area', 'Taxonomy Singular Name', 'text_domain' ),
        'menu_name'                  => __( 'Areas', 'text_domain' ),
        'all_items'                  => __( 'All Items', 'text_domain' ),
        'parent_item'                => __( 'Parent Item', 'text_domain' ),
        'parent_item_colon'          => __( 'Parent Item:', 'text_domain' ),
        'new_item_name'              => __( 'New Area', 'text_domain' ),
        'add_new_item'               => __( 'Add Area', 'text_domain' ),
        'edit_item'                  => __( 'Edit Area', 'text_domain' ),
        'update_item'                => __( 'Update Area', 'text_domain' ),
        'view_item'                  => __( 'View Area', 'text_domain' ),
        'separate_items_with_commas' => __( 'Separate items with commas', 'text_domain' ),
        'add_or_remove_items'        => __( 'Add or remove items', 'text_domain' ),
        'choose_from_most_used'      => __( 'Choose from the most used', 'text_domain' ),
        'popular_items'              => __( 'Popular Items', 'text_domain' ),
        'search_items'               => __( 'Search Items', 'text_domain' ),
        'not_found'                  => __( 'Not Found', 'text_domain' ),
        'no_terms'                   => __( 'No items', 'text_domain' ),
        'items_list'                 => __( 'Items list', 'text_domain' ),
        'items_list_navigation'      => __( 'Items list navigation', 'text_domain' ),
    );
    $args = array(
        'labels'                     => $labels,
        'hierarchical'               => true,
        'public'                     => true,
        'show_ui'                    => true,
        'show_admin_column'          => true,
        'show_in_nav_menus'          => false,
        'show_tagcloud'              => false,
    );
    register_taxonomy( 'profile_category', array( 'profile' ), $args );

}
add_action( 'init', 'tax_profile_topics');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You missed the `'show_in_rest' => true` in `register_taxonomy()`. The default value is `FALSE`, so if you use Gutenberg editor, your custom taxonomy will not be visible.

Comment: This did it. Thanks so much.

Comment: @rmlumley didn't you already have that?  I see it in the code you shared, unless you updated it after getting the answer?

Answer (score 0):

I think so that will help you.

***setup at register_taxonomy $args:***

```
$capabilities = array (
        'manage_terms' => 'publish_mysuffix', //by default only admin
        'edit_terms' => 'publish_mysuffix',
        'delete_terms' => 'publish_mysuffix',
        'assign_terms' => 'publish_mysuffix' 
      );
```

***changes, capatability_type property at cpt 'post' to:***

```
'capability_type' => 'mysuffix'
```

Then should be **grant** the **role's**:

```
$admin = get_role('my_role_name_may_admin');
$admin_caps = array(
    'read',
    'edit_pages',
    'edit_published_pages',
    'edit_others_pages',
    'publish_pages',
    'edit_mysuffix',
    'edit_others_mysuffix',
    'edit_private_mysuffix',
    'edit_published_mysuffix',
    'publish_mysuffix',
    'read_private_mysuffixs',
    'delete_mysuffix',
    'delete_others_mysuffix',
    'delete_private_mysuffix',
    'delete_published_mysuffix'
);
foreach ($admin_caps as $cap) {
    $admin->add_cap($cap);
}
```

**hook** add_action('after_setup_theme', 'add_custom_roles');